# route and config continue - I beat these two until they are completely dead

Tags: php, codeigniter

My url used to be something like

http://example.com/index.php/class/function/id

I created .htaccess and adjusted config file, now that the index.php is out of sight on every load.  I would like to also hide "class" so that my url may only look shorter i.e http://example.com/function/id. I want this because sometimes my class name is not beautiful, I don't want it to be there, thank you.....

Comment: Show us what you've done so far in your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know you can rewrite just the class name with htaccess, right?

```
RewriteRule ^prettyclass/function/([0-9]+)?$ uglyclass/function/$1 [L,NC]
```

Otherwise you will have to specify the particular route per URI in the routes config...

```
$route['some_function/:num'] = 'uglyclass/function/$1';
```

Comment: I have to admit. CI is not hard to code in but too difficult to configure its routes, illogical.

Comment: Then I suggest you never try kohana. 3.1 and greater. CI's routes are a dream compared to those.